# Why conditioning before and after join, gets different results?

Tags: mysql, subquery, join

I want to left join two tables and then return some of the records.

My first query was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM card
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_card ON card.id = user_card.card_id
WHERE card.package_id =14
AND ( user_card.user_id =  '5'
OR user_card.user_id IS NULL)
```

Then when I noticed some problems
(ie result has fewer rows than just `SELECT FROM card WHERE package_id=14`)

I wrote this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select * from card WHERE package_id=14 ) as cc
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from user_card WHERE user_id=5 ) as uu ON cc.id = uu.card_id
```

Now:

1. Why these two queries act differently?
2. How can I do it right without sub-querying ?

P.S : I'm using MySQL, and all `id` columns are `INT`.

Comment: Just curious .. in your first you have `'5'` and in your second you have `5` .. is this simply a typo?

Comment: Did you mean to leave out the `user_id IS NULL` condition on your second query?

Comment: You probably want to use `SELECT * FROM card LEFT OUTER JOIN user_card ON card.id = user_card.card_id AND user_card.user_id = 5 WHERE card.package_id =14` which is equivalent to the 2nd query.

Comment: @Chris user_id in table user_card cannot be NULL on its own, it only become NULL in the resulting joined table when there is no corresponding card_id in the user_card (right table) to the id in card table (left table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question:

In the first query, some records are filtered out **AFTER** getting the result of the left join. These rows are the ones that meet this condition:  `card.package_id =14 AND user_card.user_id <> 5` `[AND user_card.user_id IS NOT NULL]`

On the other hand, in the second query, **ALL** result rows with "card.package_id =14" are returned regardless of the value of `user_card.user_id`

Example:

```
card.id     card.package_id
11          14
12          14
13          55

user_card.card_id   user_card.user_id 
11                  5
12                  6
```

All possible values:

```
card.id package_id user_card.user_id
11      14         5
11      14         6
12      14         5
12      14         6
13      55         5
13      55         6
```

The first query will filter out the the rows with user_id=6, although the value of package_id is 14, (and will filter out all reos with package ID <> 14), so the returned values will be:

```
card.id package_id user_card.user_id
11      14         5
12      14         5
```

The second query would keep all rows with package id = 14, and give null to user id:

```
card.id package_id user_card.user_id
11      14         5
11      14         NULL
12      14         5
12      14         NULL
```

You can judge which output is needed, and based on that you chose which query to use.